# MongoError: The $subtract accumulator is a unary operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to find any solutions for this problem. I just can't figure out what is wrong.

I already tried this [Mongo subtract in group aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722968/mongo-subtract-in-group-aggregation) but no hope. The post also failed to explain further.

Here is my code:

```
 var aggregateOptions;
  aggregateOptions = [{
    $match: {

    }
  },{
    $group: {
      _id: "$customerID",
      totalAmount: { $sum: "$amount" },
      totalpaidAmount: { $sum: "$paidAmount" },
      totalAmountDue: { $subtract: ["$totalAmount", "totalpaidAmount"] }
    }
  }];

  Sale.sales.get(Sale.Schema, aggregateOptions, (err, saleRecord) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(saleRecord);

    res.json({
      pageTitle: "Customer List",
      currentUser: req.user,
      saleRecord: saleRecord,
    });
  });
```

it prompts MongoError: The $subtract accumulator is a unary operator everytime I query it.

Comment: Arithmetic operators cannot be used at `group` stage. Instead, have an additional `project` stage or  `addFields` stage that add new field with `subtract` operation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change your query part to this one:

```
aggregateOptions = [
  {
     $match: {

     }
  },
  {
     $group: {
       _id: "$customerID",
       totalAmount: { $sum: "$amount" },
       totalpaidAmount: { $sum: "$paidAmount" }
     }
  },
  {
     $addFields:{
       totalAmountDue: { $subtract: ["$totalAmount", "$totalpaidAmount"] }
     }
  }
];
```

Comment: there is a formatting problem sir +Raj but it it works. A peculiar error. I really don't understand why group stage cant do arithmetic operations.

Comment: This post is just an expanded version of my comment on your post. `$subtract` isn't an accumulator operator that keeps track of `field` state. Only `accumulator` operators can be used with `group` stage. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/.

Comment: @RahulRaj Is it correct to say that the fields of `$group` cannot refer to other fields newly declared in the same stage?